# warning: invalid memory pointer passed to a callee: What does it mean and how to fix

Tags: c, pointers, histogram, root-framework

I am trying to analyze some data. For one set of my data the code I have written works well, i.e there are no errors, results are as expected. However, if I use the same code on another set of similar data, I get this error:

```
 Generating stack trace...
 0x00007f46964680a0 in cling::IncrementalExecutor::executeWrapper(llvm::StringRef, cling::Value*) const + 0x380 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f46963fae77 in cling::Interpreter::RunFunction(clang::FunctionDecl const*, cling::Value*) + 0xa7 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f46963fc4df in cling::Interpreter::EvaluateInternal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cling::CompilationOptions, cling::Value*, cling::Transaction**, unsigned long) + 0x1df from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f46964c61f1 in cling::MetaSema::actOnxCommand(llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, cling::Value*) + 0x591 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f46964d6084 in cling::MetaParser::isXCommand(cling::MetaSema::ActionResult&, cling::Value*) + 0x194 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f46964d7476 in cling::MetaParser::isCommand(cling::MetaSema::ActionResult&, cling::Value*) + 0xa6 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f46964bf64b in cling::MetaProcessor::process(llvm::StringRef, cling::Interpreter::CompilationResult&, cling::Value*, bool) + 0x10b from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f469637b68e in <unknown> from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f469638fe72 in <unknown> from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f4696384537 in <unknown> from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007f469bb12908 in TApplication::ExecuteFile(char const*, int*, bool) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/base/src/TApplication.cxx:1156 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCore.so
 0x00007f469bb120ac in TApplication::ProcessLine(char const*, bool, int*) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/base/src/TApplication.cxx:1007 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCore.so
 0x00007f469bfe18e2 in TRint::ProcessLineNr(char const*, char const*, int*) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/rint/src/TRint.cxx:762 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libRint.so
 0x00007f469bfe1cd4 in TRint::HandleTermInput() at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/rint/src/TRint.cxx:613 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libRint.so
 0x00007f469bc66600 in TUnixSystem::CheckDescriptors() at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/unix/src/TUnixSystem.cxx:1309 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCore.so
 0x00007f469bc67f98 in TUnixSystem::DispatchOneEvent(bool) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/unix/src/TUnixSystem.cxx:1065 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCore.so
 0x00007f469bb7cd81 in TSystem::Run() at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/base/src/TSystem.cxx:412 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCore.so
 0x00007f469bb0fc7f in TApplication::Run(bool) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/base/src/TApplication.cxx:1179 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCore.so
 0x00007f469bfe32d1 in TRint::Run(bool) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/rint/src/TRint.cxx:463 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libRint.so
 0x00007f469c800a0c in <unknown> from /home/cucip/builddir/bin/root.exe
 0x00007f469af71b97 in __libc_start_main + 0xe7 from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 0x00007f469c800a6a in _start + 0x2a from /home/cucip/builddir/bin/root.exe
Error in <HandleInterpreterException>: Trying to access a pointer that points to an invalid memory address..
Execution of your code was aborted.
In file included from input_line_776:1:
/mnt/c/1/MG5_aMC_v2_6_6/Delphes/examples/HZZXT.C:167:5: warning: invalid memory pointer passed to a callee:
 if(muon1->PT < 20 | muon2->PT < 20 | abs(muon1->Eta) > 2.5 | abs(muon2->Eta) > 2.5) continue;
```

What does this error mean? And how can I fix it? 
Please let me know if more information or code is needed.

Comment: Could you paste the code snippet from this file `HZZXT.C` around the line 167?

Comment: if(muon1->PT < 20 | muon2->PT < 20 | abs(muon1->Eta) > 2.5 | abs(muon2->Eta) > 2.5) continue;
 if(muon3->PT < 20 | muon4->PT < 20 | abs(muon3->Eta) > 2.5 | abs(muon4->Eta) > 2.5) continue;
 if(muon5->PT < 20 | muon6->PT < 20 | abs(muon5->Eta) > 2.5 | abs(muon6->Eta) > 2.5) continue;

Comment: Well, please [edit] you question, there is always that little link on the left below your question to do so. Down here in the comments new information will get lost. -- And then, please provide a [example]. The lines you show have nothing to do with your error, apparently, and the line throwing the error is in the message. Are you sure that you provide valid pointers in `muon1` and `muon2`?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will check it